# Cakephp and Fancybox implementation

Tags: javascript, html, cakephp, fancybox

This is the script inside my CTP file where tigger link for fancybox is given. Using Fancybox i want to show Report Post form which is in different controller. How can i call that form inside fancybox?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {


            $("a#example1").fancybox();

            $("a#example2").fancybox({
                'overlayShow'   : false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
            });
        });
</script>
<?= $this->Html->link('Report Claim',array('controller'=>'Claim','action'=>'flag','id'=>$details['Claim']['id']),array('id'=>'example2')); ?>
```

In page source link is like this :

```
<a href="/Report-Claim/83" id="example2">Report Claim</a>
```

When I click on report claim it shows same page inside fancybox

I don't know much about Javascript and stuffs but I need to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {


            $("a#example1").fancybox();

            $("a#example2").fancybox({
                'overlayShow'   : false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
            });
        });
</script>
<?= $this->Html->link('Report Claim',array('controller'=>'Claim','action'=>'flag','id'=>$details['Claim']['id']),array('id'=>'example2')); ?>
```

I just remvoed `'id'=>$details['Claim']['id']` and now it is working perfect

Answer (score 0):

call an Ajax request with JsHelper and update the div with received data and then show the fancybox within the on-success event.